# Volume gets played instantly via Motorola Edge 30 Pro's speakers at max volume when it auto connects to wireless earbuds

Tags: bluetooth, audio, motorola, speaker

More often than not, when my wireless earbuds (Jabra Elite 75t) auto connects to my Motorola Edge 30 Pro, the volume gets played instantly via the phone's speakers at MAX volume.

I have never experienced this specific bug earlier with different combinations of devices.

Comment: "*the volume gets played instantly*" could you [edit] and clarify this part? Did you mean "the value of the current volume"?

Comment: Also, if you can edit and ask a specific question, that will help get an answer.